# Proper way to adjectivize the word "deity"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Having looked it up, no dictionary I can find lists a definition for "deitous," so I was wondering if perhaps I added the the wrong suffix to "deity" to turn it into adjective? This is more of a pedantic question, but just out of curiosity, does anyone know of a word like what I'm describing?

Comment: Try including a sample sentence where you would use the adjectival form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no English adjective that derives directly from the noun *deity*, but there's an adjective that means "of or like a god" and has the same root as *deity*:

> [**divine**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/divine)
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Of or like God or a god.
>      -- *‘heroes with divine powers’*
>      -- *‘paintings of shipwrecks being prevented by divine intervention’*
>
> **Origin**
>   Late Middle English: via Old French from Latin *divinus*, from *divus* ‘godlike’ (related to *deus* ‘god’).
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

Compare this with the [origin of *deity*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deity):

> 1250–1300; Middle English *deite* < Old French < Late Latin *deitāt-*
>   (stem of *deitās* ), equivalent to Latin *dei-* (combining form of
>   *deus* god) + *-tāt-* -ty2, formed after Latin *dīvīnitās* divinity
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

Those with an interest in etymology might enjoy [this detailed chart by John Lawler](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf) showing the common roots of various words related to *deity/divine*.

Comment: Just to add that modern French doesn't seem to have an adjectival form either, based on TLFi http://www.cnrtl.fr/portailindex/LEXI/TLFI/D/1200

Comment: Note [the etymological source](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dei.pdf); _divine_ and _deity_ are from the same root.

Comment: @JohnLawler I love your chart - fascinating! I've added it to my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Deific* might be closer to what you're after.

From the Macquarie (Australian) Dictionary:

> *deific* adjective making divine; deifying.
>
> [Late Latin *deificus* god-making, sacred]